# Django + OsX Lion + Mysql with XAMPP

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, osx-lion

I have the following on my MacBook with Osx Lion:

- Mysql running with xampp (http://www.apachefriends.org/it/xampp.html)
- Django 1.3 running in a virtualenv

I installed Mysql-python with `pip install MySQL-python`

but when trying to use manage.py syncdb I get the following error:

```
(django_1.3)Daniel-Mac:fz_biblio daniel$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/daniel/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.7-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/daniel/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.7-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
(django_1.3)Daniel-Mac:fz_biblio daniel$ mate "/Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py
> "
(django_1.3)Daniel-Mac:fz_biblio daniel$ mate /Users/daniel/Sites/django-proj/virtual-env/django_1.3/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py
```

Any idea in order to make django work with mysql in my environment?!?!

Comment: If you're just getting started, you may want to just use Postgres. The Django authors recommend Postgres over MySQL and it happens to be infinitely easier to install and configure on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted out the problem installing the right version of MySQL for my machine.

I installed MySQL 64bit version -->  [Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit)](http://www.mysql.it/downloads/mysql/)

After installing it Everything started working fine. I guess it was due to the fact that my previous installation was a 32bit one, that why mysql-python was complaining for the wrong architecture.